# Synchrotron radiation calculation details and expressing the flux

Tags: spectroscopy, accelerator-physics, synchrotron-radiation

In chapter 14 of Jackson the energy radiated per unit frequency interval per unit solid angle is given:
[image]
Integration over the angles gives:

[image]

Finally, dividing by $\hbar \omega$ equation (14.91) gives the number of photons per unit frequency interval:
[image]

Can someone detail the steps Jackson does to go from (14.91) to (14.93)? I do not understand.
Also, I want a flux expressed in photons per second per 0.1% bandwith. How can I get this from (14.93)?

The more details the better, thank you.

Comment: How is $y$ defined? I’ve never seen frequency denoted by $y$. Does eqn. (14.92), which you skipped over, have any relevant info?

Comment: What is the value of $I$ on the RHS of Eq. 14.93? Is it something like $I = \frac{8\pi e^2\gamma\omega_c}{9c}$?

Comment: I looked at my copy of *Jackson*. You need to use $y=\omega/\omega_c$ and $I=4\pi e^2\gamma^3/3\rho$, which appear immediately after (14.93), and $\omega_c=\frac32\gamma^3\frac{c}{\rho}$ from (14.81). Then the algebra works out to get from (14.91) to (14.93).

Comment: You also need $dI=\hbar\omega\,dN$.

Comment: *Also, I want…* Your second question should be a separate post. This site has a one-question-per-post rule.